# not sending a post request with axios in react js with redux form (sends nothing in post request)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, redux-form

my problem is that i going to make a post request with axios, need to send the form to the backend, but sends nothing usig the post request, im using redux form to capture and axios to send the form, and flask in the backend.
i saw another answers but doesnt work.

im using redux for the state of the app.

this is the redux-form code:

```
    import React from 'react'
    import {Field,reduxForm} from 'redux-form'
    import {connect} from 'react-redux'
    import { showResults,showOneRestaurante}from '../../actions/actions'
    const SimpleForm=props=>{

      const {handleSubmit}=props;
      const onFormSubmit=(data)=>{            
        let id=data.idRestaurante;           
        var formData = new FormData();         

        formData.append('idRestaurante',id)           
        const config={
          headers: { 
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
          }           
        }

        showOneRestaurante(formData,config)
      }
      return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onFormSubmit)}>
            <div>
                <label> Id Restaurante </label>
                      <Field
                          name='idRestaurante'
                          component='input'
                          type='text'
                          placeholder='ID  RESTAURANTE'
                      />               

            </div>        
            <button type='submit' > Submit </button>
        </form>
      )
    }

    export default connect(null)( reduxForm({
      form:'idRestautanres'
    })(SimpleForm));
```

this is the action with axios code:

```
            import React from 'react'
            import axios from 'axios'                               
            import renderRestaurantesList from '../components/restaurantesLayout/allRestaurantes'
            import qs from 'qs'                
            export const SHOW_ONE_RESTAURANTE='SHOW_ONE_RESTAURANTE';          

            export function showOneRestaurante(formData,config){               
                return (dispatch)=>(                                                                 
                    axios({
                        method:'post',
                        url:"http://127.0.0.1:5000/obtenerRestaurante",                            
                        data:qs.stringify( formData)
                    }                        
                )
                    .then(response=>{
                        console.log('showone')
                        console.log(response)
                        dispatch({type:SHOW_ONE_RESTAURANTE,payload:renderRestaurantesList(response.data)})                            
                    })
                    .catch(function(err){
                        dispatch(<div>mal</div>)
                    })
                )   
            }
```

in the last code, if i use data:qs.stringify({idRestaurante:'4'}) it works, like:

```
 axios({method:'post',
       url:"http://127.0.0.1:5000/obtenerRestaurante",
       data:qs.stringify({idRestaurante:'4'})
 }
```

instead using:
     axios({method:'post',
           url:"http://127.0.0.1:5000/obtenerRestaurante",
           data:qs.stringify( formData)
     }
but obviusly i need to use the specific data of the form, in my back-end i use flask, and to have the form information, i write the next code in flask:

```
def GetRestaurante():

    if request.method=="POST":


        PidRestaurante = request.form['idRestaurante']
```

the back works correctly using postman, and in my frontend as i said before, the information shows correctly only when i use the code qs.stringify({idRestaurante:'4'}).

this is my first question in stack overflow, i appreciate a lot the answer soon :).

Comment: did you try simply using an object instead of form data

Comment: can you give me an example please?, y need the form data because i need to capture it in a form. how  do you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const onFormSubmit=(data)=>{            
        data = { id: data.idRestaurante };
        const config={
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
          }           
        }

        showOneRestaurante(data,config)
      }
```

in showOneRestaurante

```
axios({
       method:'post',
       url:"http://127.0.0.1:5000/obtenerRestaurante",
       data:qs.stringify(data),
 })
```

Comment: is sends like i need it, thanks, but still not showing, you know why? the get request of axios works and show it, but the post not uptdate the state instantly, i had to make a flag variable to show it with another button, the form button its to send the info, and another to show the state :/